# Assignment from unset variable | What is _jQuery for?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This value is set before jQuery has been exposed to the global scope:

```
_jQuery = window.jQuery,
```

Near the end of the IIFE and after the above statement there is

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

This is from the [jQuery development source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js).

What compiler mechanism allows jQuery to do an assignment from an unset variable.

Also, what is _jQuery for in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment says, `_jQuery` backs anything that already exists in the global scope up (like older versions of jQuery). This is probably for the `jQuery.noConflict` feature.

Comment: so it does not conflict with itself? What else would be stored in window.jQuery?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist Well, that depends on whether `$.noConflict()` is called or not, and how it is called. The line you saw was the set up for the `$.noConflict` function. The actual function, decides whether or not jQuery gets `$` or `jQuery` in the global namespace. `window.jQuery` should be only jQuery, unless you pass `true` in `noConflict`, in which case, `window.jQuery` would contain your old version of jQuery.

Comment: there must be a check for `_jQuery === undefined` somewhere, if it had not been set but `$.noConflict()` was called.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist That would probably be needed if jQuery wanted to automatically solve conflicts. In this case, they've provided `noConflict` where we explicitly say there will be a conflict (or that we just want `window.$` free). So here, they just do `window.$ = _$`, which means, `undefined` if there was nothing earlier, which means the space is now free for you, or it means that your old library is back to what it was, holding `window.$`.

Comment: well...I don't use defensive coding..but I bet jQuery would.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist "Defensive" coding? You're betting jQuery makes sure that _jQuery contains something even though we're telling it we want it's global namespace to be free? jQuery doesn't control that part since it doesn't know if it's the first to load. If _jQuery is undefined, it may be defined *after* jQuery is done loading.

Answer (score 1):

That's a way for jQuery to facilitate it's noConflict functionality.  It is storing a copy of whatever was set previously to `window.jQuery` so that it can restore it later if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

That part of the code is preparation for using the `$.noConflict()` method. `window.jQuery` is either going to be an existing jQuery library that existed prior to including the one being initialized, or it will be `undefined`. Neither case should cause a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the code:

```
// Map over jQuery in case of overwrite
```

The previous values of window.jQuery and window.$ are saved for the noConflict functionality.

Comment: that doesn't make any sense..it's not mapping over jQuery...it's making an assignment to _jQuery...perhaps if they would just have removed the word `over` it would make sense `map possible previous jQuery to _jQuery` makes sense.

Comment: Probably they are referring to the var's name "jQuery", not to the variable's content. So they map the var "jQuery" - and this is exactly what they do.